# ffmpeg and nginx - restream with audio reencoding

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I use `nginx` and `ffmpeg` to restream video from my provider. Previously I use ffmpeg with arguments where I reencoding video and reencoding audio, because my server is to slow I resigned from reencoding.

So now, I use that command :

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://link.somelink.com:6565/21d12d1/17233 -map 0 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://test_ip/canal/stream
```

This works only when my provider streaming with `aac` audio codec, but sometimes my provider change audio codec to `ac3`. And then this doesn't work. I try something like this :

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 32768 -re -i http://link.somelink.com:6565/21d12d1/17233 -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://test_ip/canal/stream
```

And it all looks like it's all right in console with ffmpeg, but my restreaming video doesn't work. Ngnix throws 304 exception sometime.

Any suggestions?

Please help, 
It's very important for me...

Answer (score 0):

Ac3 is not in supported codecs list. You should encode your stream accordingly.

> RTMP supports only a limited number of codecs. The most popular RTMP video codecs are H264, Sorenson-H263 (aka flv) and audio codecs AAC, MP3, Nellymoser, Speex. If your video is encoded with these codecs (the most common pair is H264/AAC) then you do not need any conversion. Otherwise you need to convert video to one of supported codecs.

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-started-with-nginx-rtmp

Comment: Yes, I know but when I reencoding audio to aac for example, stream on ngnix doesn't work...